# Paypal returns "?" in the middle of return URL (can't GET token and PayerID)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, paypal

Paypal started to return from sandbox this URL:

`http://www.url.com/en/order/201807035911&success=true&paymentId=PAY-3VW434721W751862GLO563ZQ?token=EC-1CD5257354412893B&PayerID=AZDJ2H9PDTOYY`

A question mark in the middle of URL ( .. 63ZQ**?**token=E ..).
The URL configurated in the PHP SDK is:

`$successUrl = "http://www.url.com/en/order/201807035911&success=true";`

I can get through _GET paymentId without a problem, but can't access the token and PayerID because of the question mark.

I have no idea how to solve it in a smart way. I tried even .htaccess, that doesn't work at all (I don't get even the paymentId parameter):

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/order/(.*)&success=(.*)&paymentId=(.*)?token=(.*)&PayerID=(.*) overview.php?jazyk=$1&id=$2&success=$3&paymentId=PAY-$4&token=$5&PayerID=$6 [L]`

With this .htaccess I use for my website I can get paymentID, but not the rest.

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/order/(.*) overview.php?jazyk=$1&id=$2 [L]`

How can I access the token and PayerID parameters?

Comment: you shouldn't have your own parameters on the return url, that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd check if the configured postback URL is correct. It appears to have an `&` without a `?` preceding it to mark the beginning of the query string.

```
"http://www.url.com/en/order/201807035911&success=true"
```

You don't need to add `success=true` manually, since the status will be provided in the request's query string. Try setting it to just:

```
"http://www.url.com/en/order/201807035911"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the URL, get the stuff on the right of the `?` and use [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get the other values.

If you already have your full URL you can skip the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in the first step.

```
// your URL
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ;

// split it on the '?'
$urlParts = explode('?',$url) ;

// grab the variables and put them in $rightOfTheQuestionMark
parse_str($urlParts[1],$rightOfTheQuestionMark) ;
```

What you want is now in the array `$rightOfTheQuestionMark`